# get Identity from sql batch insert via jdbctemplate.batchupdate

Tags: sql, spring, spring-jdbc

I want to get inserted/updated row IDs(PrimaryKey) from `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate`

Is there any way to use KeyHolder like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1668361/651210) to get inserted/update row IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not, probably because the JDBC specification does not require `getGeneratedKeys` to work with `executeBatch()`, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15684917/4472840). If your driver does support it, you'll need to use plain old JDBC to access the resultset. The code would be something like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into ... values (?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ps.setXXX(1, value1);
ps.addBatch();
ps.setXXX(1, value2);
ps.addBatch();
ps.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
```